# Concatenating fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete

This is an MS Access (2010) script.

I am trying to concatenate 2 fields of a single table for 2 tables. Then I want to delete the associated record in one of the table if the concatenated field is equal in both tables (means this is a duplicate).

I know how to do that in VBA by looping through the records but I want to do that in SQL since the tables may quickly hold more than 50000 records which means the loop would go 2,500,000,000 times.

I though I could create a 2 SELECT statement in order to create the concatenated fields for both tables. The SELECT Statements will also display the ID of the underlying tables. Then I would delete the record in the appropriate table using the ID.

These are my Select statements:

```
SELECT [Tick] & [Div_ex_date] AS Expr2, tblBbgDivData.ID
FROM tblBbgDivData
GROUP BY [Tick] & [Div_ex_date], tblBbgDivData.ID;
```

And

```
SELECT [Security_Name] & [Div_ex_date] AS Expr1, tblArchiveBbgDivData.ID
FROM tblArchiveBbgDivData
GROUP BY [Security_Name] & [Div_ex_date], tblArchiveBbgDivData.ID;
```

This is my DELETE Statement:

```
DELETE tblArchiveBbgDivData.*
FROM (tblArchiveBbgDivData 
INNER JOIN qselUniqueID_Archive ON tblArchiveBbgDivData.ID = qselUniqueID_Archive.ID) 
INNER JOIN qselUniqueID_BbgDiv ON qselUniqueID_Archive.Expr1 = qselUniqueID_BbgDiv.Expr2
WHERE (((tblArchiveBbgDivData.ID)=[qselUniqueID_Archive].[ID]) 
  AND ((qselUniqueID_Archive.Expr1)=[qselUniqueID_BbgDiv].[Expr2]));
```

When I hit Datasheet view, the relevant records are displayed but when I hit Run I get "Could not delete from specified tables". Any idea how I can change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access does not work well with `JOIN`s in a `DELETE` statement. You may be better off with an `IN`:

```
DELETE tblArchiveBbgDivData.*
FROM (tblArchiveBbgDivData 
WHERE tblArchiveBbgDivData.ID IN 
   (SELECT qselUniqueID_Archive.ID 
    FROM qselUniqueID_Archive ) 
    INNER JOIN qselUniqueID_BbgDiv 
        ON qselUniqueID_Archive.Expr1 = qselUniqueID_BbgDiv.Expr2
   );
```

Note that your `WHERE` is redundant because you use the same expression in your `JOIN` syntax.